# How to write a method to add up number and save it in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning C++ and have some questions about add numbers.
Here is the code, the final result should be something like this: [Picture](http://www.bianlei.com/temporary/)
Please help me to figure it out. Otherwise, I'm in the hell..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


/* These three mothod need to be complete and achieve goal
class Vehicle{};
class Truck : public Vehicle{};
class RiverBarge : public Vehicle{};
*/

void main(){
    Vehicle *x;
    x = new Truck(1000);
    Vehicle *y;
    y = new RiverBarge(1000);
    int a;
    double b;
    while(true){
        cout<<endl<<"Add load to ";
cout<<"(1 for truck, 2 for river barge, & 0 to end): ";
        cin>>a;
        if( a == 0 )
            break;
        if( a == 1 ){
            x->welcome();
            x->details();
        } else{
            y->welcome();
            y->details();
        }
        cout<<"How many kg: ";
        cin>>b;
        if( a == 1 ){
            x->addBox(b);
        } else{
            y->addBox(b);
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"END!"<<endl<<"Truck: ";
    x->details();
    cout<<"River barge: ";
    y->details();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated:You don't have to put ` ` for each statement, copy code, paste, select all and do `Ctrl+K`

Comment: Sounds like homework. And this comment: " These three mothod need to be complete and achieve goal" gives you a hint.

Comment: @Theolodis Not homework, it is practice before a test. But I'm no much time on this, in a hurry....

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; apparently, as long as the user desires it, trucks and barges (which are vehicles, hence the base class) need to be read - this could be done via methods of the classes, as well as the output.

Comment: @Codor Please see the "picture", it's a link to the final result

Comment: If its study for a test and someone does it for you then what is the point?

Comment: @Ben If I read the source code, it will be helpful to understand this since I'm running out of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the methods you use for the classes. Vehicle needs the methods as pure virtual, to make sure that the methods of Truck and RiverBarge are called.

```
class Vehicle{
public:
    Vehicle(int canHold) : maxWeight(canHold), actualWeight(0)
    {
    }
    void welcome() = 0;
    void details(){
        cout << "the max weight: " << maxWeight << " the actual: " << actualWeight << endl;
    }
    void addBox(int weight){
        // check that weight < max weight, if so add it to actual weight
        if (actualWeight + weight <= maxWeight){
            actualWeight += weight;
            cout << "loaded" << endl;
       } else {cout << "too heavy" << endl;}
    }
protected:
    int maxWeight, actualWeight;
};

class Truck : public Vehicle {
public:
    Truck(int canHold) : Vehicle(canHold)
    {
    }

    void welcome(){
         //print welcome message
    }
};

class RiverBarge : public Vehicle {
public:
    RiverBarge(int canHold) : Vehicle(canHold)
    {
    }

    void welcome(){
         //print welcome message
    }
};
```

Comment: I did it! Watched about 50+ videos on YouTube, and now I could understand it, thanks again for the code you shared here!

Comment: @SpainshCake nice, but keep in mind that you can only learn to program if you do actually program on a regularly basis! Try to find something that passionates you and program it!

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the missing parts:

```
class Vehicle{
  float max_load;
  float current_load;
public:
  Vehicle(the_max_load): max_load(the_max_load), current_load(0.0) {}

  void welcome() const = 0;

  void details() const {
     cout<< ... <<endl;
  }

  void addBox(float load) {
     ...
  }

};

class Truck : public Vehicle{
public:
   Truck(float the_max_load): Vehicle(the_max_load) {}

   void welcome() const {
      ...
   }
};

class RiverBarge : public Vehicle{
  ...
};
```